# Objective-C - calling performSelector

Tags: objective-c, performselector

Currently i'm trying to call a selector with the following line of code:

```
    [self performSelector:@selector(locationManager:) withObject:nil afterDelay:searchAnimation.animationDuration];
```

The method i'm trying to call is:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons: (NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region { NSLog(@"check"); }
```

Can anyone help me out. This is not working because "Undeclared selector". Isn't locationmanager: the name here?

How can I call that function otherwise?

Tanks!

Comment: The selector is `locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:`, no more, no less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED** You can't use `performSelector` in this case, it only takes 0 or 1 arguments. Thanks @rmaddy.

I don't understand what y'r trying to achieve, but maybe you should use the [CGD dispatch_after](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_after)

**For example:**

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(searchAnimation.animationDuration * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     <# call the delegate method here #>
});
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: You can't use the `performSelector...` method here since the selector has more than one parameter. You must use the `dispatch_after` function and call the method directly.

Comment: Of course you can, if you don't want to send arguments to the function. Anyway, i think you should read better my answer, i recommend the usage of dispatch_after. Cheers.

Comment: No, you can't. In this case the selector takes 3 arguments. The docs for `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` clearly state that the selector must take 0 or 1 arguments. And yes, I was agreeing with you that you should use `dispatch_after`. That part is correct.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I have a category with a different performSelector that uses `NSInvocation` that handles multiple arguments. Sorry. I will edit the answer in order to make it correct. Thanks a lot :)